# Anyway of knowing if a tab app is loading in the new timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

Is there anyway to detect if the tab app is being loading in the new timeline or not? I got clients asking to upgrade my layout but not all of them have upgraded so it makes it hard to do that. If I had a way to detect this it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that by looking for an album called "Cover Photos" on the album list of that page. Here's a sample:

http://graph.facebook.com/-page_id-/albums?fields=name

You don't need a token unless the page isn't published yet.

The problem with this approach is that some pages still don't have cover picture yet, but it's the minority.